# Greedy Attempt for covering all the numbers with the given intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals

> Let `S` be a set of intervals (containing n number of intervals) of the natural numbers that might overlap and N be a list of numbers (containing n number of numbers).

I want to find the smallest subset (let's call P) of S such that for each number
in our list N, there exists at least one interval in P that contains it. The intervals in P are allowed to overlap.

Trivial example:

```
S = {[1..4], [2..7], [3..5], [8..15], [9..13]}
N = [1, 4, 5]
// so P = {[1..4], [2..7]}
```

I think a dynamic algorithm might not work always, so if anybody knows of a solution to this problem (or a similar one that can be converted into), that would be great. I am trying to make a O(n^2 solution)

---

Here is one greedy approach

```
P = {}
for each q in N: // O(n)
    if q in P // O(n)
        continue
    for each i in S // O(n)
        if q in I: // O(n)
           P.add(i)
           break
```

But that is O(n^4).. Any help with creating a greedy approach that is O(n^2) would be great!

Thanks!

---

*** Update: *** I've been slamming at this problem and I *think* I have an O(n^2) solution!!

Let me know if you think I'm right!!!

```
N = MergeSort (N)
upper, lower = infinity, -1
P = empty set
for each q in N do
     if (q>=lower and q<=upper)=False
          max_interval = [-infinity, infinity]
          for each r in S do
              if q in r then
                 if r.rightEndPoint > max_interval.rightEndPoint
                     max_interval = r
          P.append(max_interval)
          lower = max_interval.leftEndPoint
          upper = max_interval.rightEndPoint
          S.remove(max_interval)
```

I think this should work!! I'm trying to find a counter solution; but yeah!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covering all the numbers with the given intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604562/covering-all-the-numbers-with-the-given-intervals)

Comment: Thanks, but this has slightly different constraints than that problem. Also I am trying to derive a O(n^2) algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is similar to set cover problem, which is NP-complete (i.e., arguably has no solution faster than exponential). What makes it different is that intervals always cover adjacent elements (not arbitrary subset of N), which opens ways for faster solutions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

I think that the solution proposed by Mike is good enough. But I think I have quite straightforward O(N^2) greedy algo. It starts like the Mike's one (moreover, I believe Mike's solution can also be improved in similar way):

1. You sort your N numbers and place them sorted into array ELEM; COMPLEXITY O(N*lg N);
2. Using binary search, for each interval S[i] you identify starting and ending index of elements in ELEM that are covered by S[i]. Say, you place this pair of numbers into array COVER, the difference between the two indices tells you how many elements you cover, for simplicity, let us place it array COVER_COUNT; COMPLEXITY O(N*lg N);
3. You introduce index pointer p, that shows till which element in ELEM, your N is already covered. you set p = 0, meaning that all elements up to 0-th (excluded) are initially covered (i.e., no elements); Complexity O(1). Moreover you introduce boolean array IS_INCLUDED, that reflects if interval S[i] is already included in your coverage set. Complexity O(N)
4. Then you start from the 0-th element in ELEM and see what is the interval that contains ELEM[0] and has greater coverage COVER_COUNT[i]. Imagine that it is i-th interval. We then mark it as included by setting IS_INCLUDED[i] to true. Then you set p to end[i] + 1 where end[i] is the ending index in COVER[i] pair (indeed now all elements til end[i] are covered). Then, knowing p you update all elements in COVER_COUNT so that they reflect how many elements of not yet covered elements each interval covers (this can be easily done in O(N) time). Then you perform the same step for ELEM[p] and continues till p >= ELEM.length. It can be observed that the overall complexity is O(N^2).

You finish in O(n^2) and in IS_INCLUDED has true for intervals of S included in optimal cover set

Let me know if this solution seems reasonable to you and if I calculated everything well.

P.S. Just wanted to add that the optimality of ythe solution found by algo can be proved by induction and contradiction. By contradiction, it is easy to show that at least one optimal solution includes the longest interval of those covering element ELEM[0]. If so, by induction we can show that for each next element in algo, we can keep on following the strategy of selelcting the interval that is the longest with respect to the number of remaining elements covered and that covers the leftmost yet uncovered element.

Comment: Hey Heorhi, Thanks a lot!! Your solution is pretty complex! I just updated the question with a solution that I invented that I think should work!! but I'm not entirely sure; would you be able to check it out?

Comment: I am answering here, since I do not have enough reputation to comment in the original question. Your solution seems to be similar to mine but instead of considering the absolute length of intervals you must consider length in terms of numbers that are still uncovered after previous iterations. YOur solution will still remain O(N^2) though. To exemplify, here is where your solution will not find the optimum: N= {1, 4, 7} S= {(1,4)(2,6)(6,7)}. Your solution will include all intervals, while it is enough to include only S[0] and S[2]

Comment: Hmm, thanks a lot! I am checking this out. So you're proposing that I change `if r.rightEndPoint < max_interval.rightEndPoint` to `if |r.rightEndPoint - r.leftEndPoint| < |max_interval.rightEndPoint - max_interval.leftEndPoint|` ? Drat, I thought I had it! I am checking this out right now.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked and with my algorithm I get S[0] and S[2] with that counter-example. At `if (q>=lower and q<=upper)=False` when lower is equal to 1 and upper is equal to 4, so S[1] does not go through.

Comment: That is, we first go to n[0] (which is 1) first grab S[0], set upper to 4 and lower 1; then go to n[1] which is 4; its already within upper and lower, skip! then go to n[2], add S[2] and set upper to 7 and lower to 6.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you start from left and cover it up to right. Sorry, but it is hard to get through the code without comments and annotations. Try this counterexample then: N = {1, 6, 8}, S = {(1,5), (2,7), (6,8)} :)

Comment: Okay hmm. I think it should still work. I just tried that counter-example out a few times. So start at N=1, add S[0]; set upper to 5 and lower to 1. Then we look for the set that contains the next Number, but has the highest right end point. For N=6, that would be S[2], since 8>7. So I would get S[0] and S[2].

Comment: Hmm, it picks S[0] and S[2] (sorry i miscommented before, just updated that comment). It greedily picks the interval that contains the current number but has the highest right end point.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Your solution works the same as mine in terms of complexity but definitely easier. Sorry, I was too fast to read your code and did not get the idea. Congrats!%)

Comment: Woooooo, I am very happy!! Haha. Thanks a lot heorhi for the assurance. I didn't think I did it!!

Comment: I think in your code it is written if r.rightEndPoint < max_interval.rightEndPoint, and should be >

Comment: Oh yeah haha - Thanks for that :)! I mistyped that part while writing the question, but on paper, I did what you said.

Comment: On a side note: would you happen to know a formal reasoning why my solution is always optimal? I tried many many different things and eventually landed on this.

Comment: It is possibile to prove that the algo is optimal. You can start by showing that the first interval S1 is chosen correctly, i.e., among optimal solutions (they can be many) there must be at least one that contains s1. After that you use induction and show that at each step you do well.

Comment: Thanks heorhi! I might need further help on the optimality proof as I honestly don't quite understand how to do that on my own. If possible, Would you mind modifying your answer to add details on this proof?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but mb some think like this.
1) For each interval create a list with elements from `N` witch contain in interval, it will take `O(n^2)` lets call it `Q[i]` for `S[i]`
2) Then sort our `S` by length of `Q[i]`, `O(n*lg(n))`
3) Go throw this array excluding `Q[i]` from `N` `O(n)` and from `Q[i+1]...Q[n]` = `O(n^2)`
4) Repeat 2 while `N` is not empty.
It's not `O(n^2)`, it's `O(n^3)` but if you can use hashmap, i think you can improve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yeah `O(n^2)` seems to be hard to get it to. I've been trying a ton of things. Thanks again!